# Selecting all rows based on a distinct column in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table with some data which I want to select rows with unique dates using the .NET core entity framework. I want to return the results as a list of the unique rows. Here is the code.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Records>> GetUniqueRecordsByDate(int bId)
{
     var rowsToReturn = await _context.Records
                .Where(b => b.SId == bId)
                .Select(d => d.Date)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(d => d)
                .ToListAsync();
     return rowsToReturn;
}
```

I'm trying to apply the above code but I get this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<
>   System.Linq.IGrouping<
>   System.DateTime, Test.API.Models.Records>>'to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<
>   Test.API.Models.Record>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Is there any other way that I can implement to get my expectations or I'm I missing something in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a `DTO` as follows:

```
public class RecordsByDateDTO
{
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public List<Record> Records {get; set;}
}
```

To select rows with unique dates, you have to use `.GroupBy` and write your `GetUniqueRecordsByDate` method as follows:

```
public async Task<List<RecordsByDateDTO>> GetUniqueRecordsByDate(int bId)
{
     var recordsByDate = await _context.Records.Where(r => r.SId == bId).GroupBy(r => r.Date)
                              .Select(group => new RecordsByDateDTO
                              {
                                   Date =  group.Key,
                                   Records = group.ToList()
                              }).OrderBy(r => r. Date).ToListAsync();

    return recordsByDate;
}
```

Comment: The error is still appearing. Let me add also that the code is inside a function of type Task<IEnumerable<Records>> which should return the list of records. I don't know if this is the cause of the error.

Comment: Are you using` IEnumerable<Record>' instead of `var` to the `recordsByDate` variable?

Comment: I'm using the var but after the execution is complete the function needs to return the recordsByDate. the returned recordsByDate is the one that produces the error.This is the function.                                                                                                         public async Task<IEnumerable<Records>> GetUniqueRecordsByDate(int bId)
        {   // the above code you provided is placed here. and at the end I return the recordsByDate }

Comment: How can I do that. Team viewer?

Comment: My internet connection is not stable and you may experience some delays. Can I provide something else that can help. A file or something

Comment: Okay no need team viewer please! Check my updated answer. You posted incomplete code in your question that's why it was the problem.

Comment: I had to create the DTO as you said and changed my function. This now works. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

```
var rowsToReturn = await _context.Records
            .Where(b => b.SId == bId)
            .Select(d => d.Date)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(d => d)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToListAsync();
return rowsToReturn;
```

Use AsEnumerable() before ToListAsync(). It will work.

Comment: Caution: `AsEnumerable` will cause the entire table to be copied into memory.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` nullifies all the benefits of `ToListAsync`. Just don't use it