# Distinct on with entity framework core

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Hi I was wondering if there was a way to use disinct on with ef core? I have looked through the npgsql documentation and could not find anything which would help me. So am I out of luck? Or is there some workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting all rows based on a distinct column in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468767/selecting-all-rows-based-on-a-distinct-column-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: I have no knowledge of the entity framework. But DISTINCT ON is a PostgreSQL specific function. So a more general database framework which might support other DBMS as well usually does not support this feature. A possible work-around could be using the row_number() window function if it is supported by the framework. Most major DBMS support this.

Comment: This feature is coming to DotNet 6 (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27687)
An open issue to implement it is waiting at npgsql (https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/894)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that we can do it only with FromSql for now, and it's a feature of Postgres:

```
if (context.Database.IsNpgsql()) // check Postgres provider
{
    var query = context.SomeData.FromSql("select distinct on (id) * from some_data order by id, date desc");
   // actions query.ToListAsync(), query.CountAsync() etc
   // ...
}
else
{
   // Other providers/exception
}
```